# My iPhone's Lockscreen clock wont update without unlocking the phone

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1.  It is Jailbroken, and the time on the lock screen won't update unless I unlock the phone.  My friend's phone is also Jailkroken (a 4S running 5.1.1) and she has the same problem.

Has anyone else with this problem found a solution to it?  It is actually very incontinent and even annoying.

I have ClockHide and AndroidLocXT installed.  I'm not sure if those have anything to do with the problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly to do with the modifications of the operating system. Either try uninstalling related mods or restore the device. This is not a problem you'd see with an unjailbroken iPhone.
And get that incontinence seen to :).